# Cyrillic (Russian / Ukrainian) input source types Latin letters on Asus Zenbook UX331UN

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, asus, cyrillic

On Ubuntu 18.04 input sources Russian / Ukrainian type latin letters. When I open "Keyboard layout" is correct (Cyrillic). I found that input source "Russian (Ukraine, standard RSTU)" type correctly Cyrillic but layout it's strange. Does someone found how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the other input sources with "ukrainian" in their names? On my Dell computer "Russian (Ukraine, standard RSTU)" type cyrillic letters but I can't tell if the layout is correct, I am not used to Ukrainian. There is long discussion about the topic at: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30658 I don't know enough russian to understand.

Comment: Just found a solution. It's necessary to reboot Ubuntu after adding a new keyboard layout to make a new layout work properly. Strange behavior to set new layout. Both languages now work correctly.

Comment: Strange indeed, at my end it was not necessary to reboot. Glad it worked for you eventually.

Comment: alt+f2 then type "r" (without quotes) and hit Enter

Comment: I see, this command restarts just GUI. Thanks!

Comment: @DenysPasishnyi, please make that as answer so we can vote on it. Thanks!